# Spider identification assistance Phoenix

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Anyone know what kind of spider this is? They seem to be in the walls of my house...

[image]

LocationL Phoenix, AZ, USA

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice silhouette of a male Southern House Spider, Kukulcania hibernalis.  That bizarre body, with the gigantic, forward-projecting, 'jackknife' chelicerae is unique and unmistakable.  These are quite harmless spiders.  A link to some useful information is below:
https://bugguide.net/node/view/26400
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sure does look like a Hobo spider but your photos don't show everything more
Photos could possibly pinpoint the spider and try to stay away this spiders could be a serious concern(really serious) and they're known to bite you even though you're not doing anything